# Paths on a disconnected manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, calculus-of-variations

I would like to check my understanding of the following.

Let *M* be a smooth embedded submanifold of $R^n$, and let $q_1,q_2$ be points in *M*.

Define "a path on *M* between $q_1, q_2$" as a $C^2$ map $p: \mathbb{R} \supseteq [a,b] \rightarrow M$, for some $a,b$, such that $p(a)=q_1, p(b)=q_2$.

My question is:

- is it correctly understood that if $M$ is not connected, such a path might not exist between arbitrary points $q_1, q_2$?
- Context: I'm studying mechanics and calculus of variations on manifolds (Lie groups in particular), reading Marsdens *Introduction to mechanics and symmetry* and Darryl Holms *Geometric mechanics and symmetry*. There it seems to be assumed that such paths (and "variations" of these) always exist, possibly by partitioning $[a,b]$ into subpaths contained in different coordinate domains. But this "patching" of subpaths does not create a continuous path, does it?

My background: I studied some differential geometry through Lee's *Introduction to smooth manifolds*.

**Edit:**

Construction of a path between arbitrary points, $q_1, q_2$:

Let $q_1$ be contained in the chart $(U \subset M, \varphi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n)$, and $q_2$ in $(V, \phi)$, where $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$ (this is without loss of generality).

Pick a point $q \in U \cap V$. Then we can find a path $p_1$ from $q_1$ to $q$ in $U$,  $p_1 = \varphi^{-1} \circ h  : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow U$, where $h : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is some continuous parameterized curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I.e. it is continuous and fulfills $p_1(a)=q_1$ and $p_1(k) = q$ for some $a,k \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Likewise, we can find a path $p_2$ in $V$ such that $p_2(k)=q$, $p_2(b) = q_2$.

I *would think* that, by some homeomorphic transformation of the $\mathbb{R}^n$-coordinates of each path, we can choose $a < k < b$, and construct the paths such that $p_1(k)=p_2(k)$ (as assumed above).

Now

$$
p(t)= 
\begin{cases}
    p_1(t) ,& \text{if } t\in [a,k)\\
    p_2(t) ,& \text{if } t\in [k,b]
\end{cases}
$$

is a continuous path between $q_1, q_2$.

If the above construction is correct, doesn't this show that M is connected? I.e. a contradiction.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you're right. If $M$ is not connected and you take $q_1$ and $q_2$ in different connected components, then such a path cannot exist. Maybe the author assumes the manifold is connected or more probably, the points lie in the same connected component.

Comment: $C^k$ manifolds are connected iff they are path-connected iff they are path-connected by $C^k$ paths.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question slightly - if you would look at it again, I would be grateful.

Comment: As long as the endpoints of your 'patches' match up, the result is continuous. It is not $C^k$. One needs a little additional argument to smooth out the kinks.

Comment: If that is possible, isn't M then connected? I edited the post again, where I tried to construct the path consisting of "patches" from different charts.

Comment: You're assuming that $\varphi(U)$ and $\phi(V)$ are connected. In combination with $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$, this is not always possible.